# deletion of question which has one answer with upvote

Tags: discussion

I had given an answer to one question & then my answer got two up votes. After two days that question is deleted. I don't know who & why deleted that question. It's ok if someone feels that question is not good or not enough explanatory & he deletes that question. But with this deletion I lost my reputation by 20; which I had got for my answer via up voting. This is not fair. Because I had got that votes because someone felt that this answer is useful. So my question is how can you deduct my reputation by 20 without any of my mistake.

Comment: Part of the reason why the rep is removed is to discourage answering bad questions.

Comment: That means it is to discourage good answers too. If two people up vote that answer that means it was useful for them. I think question deletion is OK. But if there is up vote for an answer even though question was bad & that answer is helping someone, there should not be a deduction of reputation. I don's see anything fair in that.

Comment: Initially i left one answer with two upvotes before i got the privilege to comment and when i get the privilege it will turned to comment and i got minus reputation. Interesting Question.

Comment: Reputation is overrated. Just wait and do other stuff and you'll get plenty of these virtual hugs. If the question was so bad that it had to be deleted then the answer is not regarded as much helpful either which is reasonable. Don't take it personally, it just happens from time to time. You might want to think about upvoting questions you are going to answer in order to make it more likely that they stay open.

Comment: I wonder: How can answering bad questions be discouraged if there is a gold badge (Reversal) for providing a really good answer (+20) to a bad question (-5)?

Comment: @tobias_k — One conversation around the reversal badge: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279285/can-we-retire-the-reversal-badge-on-main-sites-and-keep-it-only-for-meta-sites

Comment: I just lost 35 points due to the question deletion. I think the user who already has received an answer which solves his problem should not be allowed to delete the question after selecting the correct answer.
Moderators or administrators deleting the question would not be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

### [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Only really bad questions (offensive, spam, "plz dbug [10000 lines of code]", etc.) get removed by delete votes (the rest closed). Those questions don't deserve answers, so all answers are deleted, reputation taken back.

That said, it might have been wrongfully deleted (unlikely), but I don't know since I don't have 10k rep and you haven't posted the question.

Comment: No, a question with answers can't be deleted by owner.