# Question with answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

There is a question I am pretty sure I posted an answer for it. However by checking the question later today it was deleted to my surprize.

This is the link to a comment of the deleted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438619/async-http-post-in-android/23438695?noredirect=1#comment35925249_23438695

I am surprized that questions with answers can be deleted, I remember that this only happens if a questions has serious problems (spam, hate-speech etc. ) and a moderator decides to clean it up. Not the case for this one..

There is also a related question, but it lacked the actual link to the deleted question: [deletion of question which has one answer with upvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250868/deletion-of-question-which-has-one-answer-with-upvote)

So now the actual question: Why questions **with answers** and **without serious problems** can get deleted? Is it maybe a bug?

Side-note: The poster of this question has posted same question later again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439194/android-http-post-async

Comment: If the answer has upvotes, the question can't be deleted by its owner.  In this case the answer has no upvotes so it could be deleted

Comment: I see. Anyhow, I won't answer the re-posted question again.. I'll let my answer rest in peace :-P

Comment: This just happened to me for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364550/prolog-user-choice-coffee-menu) with a new user.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yeah, the author of that question is not being very friendly.

We discourage folks from such behavior, but respect the need for some to remove misguided questions even after an answer has been received.

Posting it *again* after doing so is abusive however. The author has been invited to take a short break from asking questions.

Comment: Yeah, "short" indeed.

Comment: "*invited*" — Yup, as if it's optional :P

Comment: How could the author delete this question with answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518441/modal-window-is-always-visible

Comment: One of the answers was deleted by its author prior to the question's deletion, @mplungjan