# Deleted post deleted my painstakingly crafted answer

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-questions

I worked really hard to create an answer to a question.  There was an in-depth response, a fully functional working code example that took 4+ hours to create.  Then I watched as the "deleted by" popup appeared -- the original poster deleted their question.

Is what I just learned to first upvote any question that I deem worthy of crafting a detailed response to?  (Assuming my own upvote would then prevent the user from deleting their question?  I need confirmation that this mechanic would indeed work.  If I upvoted it before answering, would that have prevented it from being deleted?  I ask because of this [Question with answer deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253374/question-with-answer-deleted))

Anyway, I think that's what I've just learned.  It severely sucks that I had to learn this the hard way though.  I wonder how many other users will get burned by answering a "0" question.

Today Stack Overflow gave me disincentive for answering a "0" question without making the potential cost (all my hard word deleted) known to me and that doesn't seem right.

**EDIT:** *Here's a follow-up to help put this in context, since this post was predicated on me being given some misinformation. The most valuable information I got after asking this is that **upvoting a question does not protect it from being self-deleted by the asker**.  Thanks, everyone for that clarification.  It definitely invalidates the approach I proposed to working around the problem (upvoting before answering). However it doesn't invalidate the rest of my reaction (being miffed about putting effort into a question that can be deleted.)  Admittedly, I'm glad I expressed this in the context that I experienced it, though, because it was an authentic reaction.  My feeling of being once bitten twice shy regarding putting effort into answering a question that has the potential to just be deleted still seems valid.*

Comment: Just ask the question yourself.

Comment: "*If I upvoted it before answering, would that have prevented it from being deleted?*" No. Self-deletion is only prevented by having an upvoted *answer*, not the question.

Comment: If what you want is confirmation that by upvoting a question you will prevent that question being deleted by its owner, we can't give you that. But you should use your votes where you feel they are appropriate, not just because to "protect" an answer of yours.

Comment: Note that deleting a question immediately after it has been answered is a big red flag to the question ban algorithm so it won't take much of that for the questioner to be unable to ask any more questions.

Comment: Had you actually posted your answer? Or were you still writing it? Had you communicated with the question asker via comments?

Comment: @RobertLongson Not that that matters; they'll just jettison the account and make another one.  If a user deletes a question as soon as they get an answer, then I bet they're used to being downvoted, and are familiar with circumventing the quality ban.

Comment: On Hans' point, see also the related discussion at [*No comments on deleted questions means no way to tell the poster they shouldn't have deleted the question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375183/2751851).

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839079/why-does-the-red-blocks-skip-a-block-in-p5-js/52839700#52839700) the answer you are talking about?

Comment: looks like it. Sounds like a "fix my code" question. I wouldn't invest 4 hours of my time answering that. 4 _minutes_ maybe.

Comment: One additional warning sign to watch for, outside non-positively-scoring Qs, anonymous or 1-rep askers or other people commenting to ask for clarification or other edits: if the Q smells like a homework question. One common cause for self-deletion is by students who want people to answer their homework or assignments for them, but once they get their answer they don’t want any evidence that profs or automated plagiarism scrapers to find, because they intend to submit your work as their own.

Comment: @DanBron that's an _excellent_ point. I never thought of that.

Answer (score 14):

If you honestly think that it's a high quality question that is a useful addition to the programming community at large (meaning it's a problem others would have, is on topic, doesn't already have readily accessible solutions, etc.) then [ask the question yourself, and post your answer to your new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375398/deleted-post-deleted-my-painstakingly-crafted-answer#comment638629_375398).

If the question isn't worth re-asking, then it means the author was appropriate to delete it, and it didn't actually belong here to begin with.

As has already been mentioned, upvoting the question does nothing to stop it from being deleted on a technical standpoint.  It may or may not from a social standpoint.  But the real takeaway here is to *answer questions that you naturally choose to upvote*, not to upvote any question that you answer.  If you aren't inclined to upvote the question before you've even decided on answering it, you probably shouldn't be answering it, because you don't think it's a good question.

Comment: That's a bold statement that "if the question isn't worth re-asking then [..] it didn't actually belong here to begin with."  Doesn't really jive with my life philosophy of whether or not I choose to answer someone's question.  But I see how it's business savvy for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Wyck If you don't agree with that then that means you either don't think it's worth asking a question that you think is a high quality, appropriate, question that would be useful to the community as a whole, or that you have a habit of answering questions that *aren't* useful or that aren't appropriate for the site.  Normally I'd say that asking a quality question and providing a quality answer is a lot of work, even if you have an idea, and people may sensibly not want to put in the time, but in the example here both the question and answer *already exist*, so it's just a copy-paste job.

Comment: I guarantee it's the latter (in the habit of answering questions that aren't useful or appropriate).  I answer questions that people ask.  I don't care to consider whether or not they are useful or appropriate.  Stack overflow allows me to answer before anyone has deemed the question to be useful or appropriate.  Perhaps to enforce your policy, the question should pass some kind of usefulness and appropriateness test before allowing people to invest their time on an answer?

Comment: @Wyck We would all *adore* that feature.  We've been asking for it for *years*.  There is some motion in this direction; I have specifically in mind the work-in-progress "ask a question wizard".  But there's also been a lot of pushback on making things easier for answerers at the expense of askers. There's been a lot of recent discussion, debate, and drama about this on MSE. The prevailing conclusion is that SE needs new users to thrive, and will attract them even at the cost of their expert user base.

Answer (score 6):

> Is what I just learned to first upvote any question that I deem worthy of crafting a detailed response to?

That is what you learned only if that is what you chose to take from this experience. But it is not the lesson you should take from this. The lesson to take from this is that this kind of thing happens, and that you shouldn't take too much to heart.

Answering good quality questions from responsive users is the best way to avoid this situations, but even then nobody can give you any assurances that this wont happen again.

It's not clear from your question if you had actually posted your answer or you were still in the process of writing it.

**If you hadn't still posted your answer**, and the question was deleted... well, nothing to do, really. It happens. For such an involved answer communicating with the asker is important, but even if you did you had no guarantees that the user wouldn't delete the question before you were done.

**If you had posted your answer**, you still have a link to the Q&A accessible through your profile. You can use that to repost that question and repurpose your answer.

In the general sense, upvoting a question **does not protect it from self-deletion**. (What protects a question from self-deletion is having upvoted or accepted answers).

An upvoted question is less likely to be self-deleted, since many users would be disinclined to lose the rep.  But **that's not a good use of votes**. While your votes are your own, and as long as they are not fraudulent you have complete freedom in how to use them, it would be really great if you upvoted content because you thought it was good and useful, not to give a measure of protection to your own posts.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have acknowledged in an edit to my post that my proposed tactic of up-voting the question before answering would *not* prevent the question from being self-deleted.   I appreciate you clarifying that part of it directly.